# Using Memcpy to append some Char* to a buffer containing Char*

Tags: c

I am writing a method to append some data to a buffer.

The Buffer looks like:

```
Buffer *new_buffer(size_t reserved) {
    Buffer* buffer = malloc(sizeof(Buffer));
    buffer->data   = (char*)calloc(reserved, sizeof(char));
    buffer->length = reserved;
    return buffer;
}
```

I would like to append data to the buffer, the method I have written is as follows:

```
void append_buffer(Buffer *buffer, char *data, size_t length) {
    if( buffer->length <= length ) {
        buffer->length = buffer->length + length;
        buffer->data   = realloc( buffer->data, buffer->length * 2 );
    }
    memcpy( &buffer->data[ strlen( buffer->data ) - 1 ], data, length );

}
```

Note that the size parameter is just the size of the array to append.

i.e.

```
append_buffer(buffer, data, len_data);
```

I believe there is errors with my memcpy;

The thought process is to use memcpy to place the data into memory for the last character in the buffer; so that we can avoid the terminating character.

Running this just doesn't append any data and I'm not really sure why!

Comment: Exponential growth (`*2`) is probably not a good idea. Also your code isn't checking that `calloc` and `realloc` failed.

Comment: Are these buffers meant to contain single-byte character data or binary data? I don't think using `strlen` is appropriate here (and it won't work as-intended if you're using UTF-16, for example).

Comment: it should be + sizeof(newthingtoadd), I am not sure what I was thinking here

Comment: I strongly suggest renaming your parameters. When I see `char* data, size-t length` I expect `length` to refer to the length of data pointed-to by `data` instead of the desired total length of the buffer after reallocation.

Comment: This is binary data, although im not sure how to go about 'strlen' else wise

Comment: (a) Is `buffer->length` the length of the actual data in the buffer or just the length of space reserved, and the data currently in the buffer might be shorter? If the latter, how do you know the length of the data in the buffer? (b) In `append_buffer`, testing `buffer->length <= length` is wrong. Judging by the `memcpy`, you are going to add `length` more bytes to the buffer, so you need to have space for the amount of current data in the buffer plus `length`. Overall, it looks like you need to rethink how to keep track of space reserved and space currently used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using buffers in C that contain arbitrary binary data you need to store two length fields: the capacity of the buffer as-allocated, and the amount of data currently stored in the buffer.

(For comparison to C#/.NET and Java, this is like how `List<T>` (`ArrayList` in Java) has both an internal `T[].Length` and a separate `Count` value).

I've rewritten your code to show how I would do it. Note that:

- The `Buffer` struct stores both `capacity` and `length`.
- The code uses `assert()` to validate parameters and verify that allocations succeeded. This is only for demonstration purposes because `assert` is removed from the program if `NDEBUG` is defiend, whereas memory allocations should always be verified.
- I separated the logic for appending (`append_buffer`) from the logic for reallocating the buffer (`expand_buffer`).

Like so:

```
#undef NDEBUG // So `assert` is always compiled.

struct Buffer {
    char*  data;
    size_t capacity; // Size of the actual allocated space
    size_t length;   // Amount of space currently used
};

struct Buffer* new_buffer( size_t initialCapacity ) {
    struct Buffer* info = malloc( sizeof(Buffer) ); // Allocate space for the metadata
    assert( info ); // Always ensure allocation succeeded!
    info->data = calloc( initialCapacity, sizeof(char) );
    assert( info->data );
    info->capacity = initialCapacity;
    info->length   = 0;
    return info;
}

void append_buffer( struct Buffer* buffer, char* data, size_t dataLength ) {
    assert( buffer ); // Parameter argument validation
    assert( data );
    if( dataLength == 0 ) return;

    size_t remainingCapacity = buffer->capacity - buffer->length;
    if( remainingCapacity < dataLength ) {
        size_t desiredCapacity = buffer->capacity + dataLength; // You might want to add a growth factor here
        expand_buffer( buffer, desiredCapacity );
    }

    char* start = buffer->data + buffer->length;
    memcpy( start, data, dataLength );
    buffer->length += dataLength;
}

void expand_buffer( struct Buffer* buffer, size_t desiredCapacity ) {
    assert( buffer );
    assert( buffer->data );
    char* newData = realloc( buffer->data, desiredCapacity );
    assert( newData );
    buffer->data     = newData;
    buffer->capacity = desiredCapacity;
    // buffer->length remains unchanged
}

void destroy_buffer( struct Buffer* buffer ) {
    assert( buffer );

    if( buffer-> data ) {
        free( buffer->data );
        buffer->data = NULL;
    }

    free( buffer );
}
```

Comment: I thought, length and count in C# is the same.

Comment: @kame If you have a single array `T[]`, yes - but other data-structures like `List<T>`, `Stack<T>`, etc are built on-top of `T[]` and that's when `T[].Length` is the internal array capacity which is separate from the exposed `.Count` property.